# simple way to reverse proxy https resource to plain http?

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy

The following nginx codes won't forward resources of `https://ooo.xxx/` to plain http content, because nginx doesn't support CONNECT when proxying(correct me if wrong). What I want is that, when user visit `http://mysite/https-site/somepage`, he/she will actually see the content of `https://ooo.xxx/somepage`.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /https-site {
        proxy_pass https://ooo.xxx;
    }
}
```

I know if makes nginx listen on port 443 with a self-signed SSL certificate, it will work. But I don't want users to visit `https://mysite/` instead, and that also requires to ignore the SSL certificate warning from the browser.

Any approaches are welcome(even irrelevant to nginx). Thanks.

Comment: You want to make secure content insecure?

Comment: For some reasons, users can not reach the target https site. So I want to proxy it to users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you insistent on using nginx, or could you use apache instead?

[Here's a reference](http://objectmix.com/apache/676906-can-apache-proxy-convert-http-request-https-proxy-https-server.html) to someone else doing something similar to what you want with apache and [here's another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977215/how-to-make-apache-proxy-http-requests-to-https) and [here's another](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Maybe I misunderstand....are you trying to do this:

> client pc ---- http ---- ngnix ---- https ---- target https host

Essentially having the ngix box be a man in the middle and decrypting the https traffic to allow the client to access the site over http?